# Building a recursive series

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I need to build a recursive series to this problem:
An = number of subsets of  A= {-n,....,-1,1,.....,n} which Do not contain any two positive consecutive numbers and Do not contain שdditive inverse numbers
note that 0 does not belong to the group.

as the title says, I need to build a recursive series and starting conditions.

Thanks,

Comment: I imagine you mean sub*sets*?  Your condition on the positive numbers is that no two *consecutive* positive numbers can appear in the subset.  Your condition for negative numbers is different however, "*do not contain two negative numbers."  Did you intend that?  Or did you intend the condition to be similar, "*do not contain two* **consecutive** *negative numbers*?"

Comment: Suppose you knew how to count $A_k$ for all $k$ strictly less than $n$.  Then the subsets satisfying the conditions will either, 1) have $-n$ and not $n$, 2) have $n$ and not $-n$, 3) have $-n$ and $n$, or 4) not have either of $-n$ or $n$.  Counting how many subsets satisfying the conditions for cases 3) and 4) should be easy (*you know how to count $A_{n-1}$ and $A_{n-2}$ by induction hypothesis, how do those relate?*).  Try thinking about how to count the cases 1 and 2, perhaps have a second sequence you are counting simultaneously, the number of subsets of $\{-n+1,\dots,-1,1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: If the condition is indeed symmetric, (*avoid consecutive even numbers and avoid consecutive odd numbers*), relate this problem to the problem of counting $B_n$ where $B_n$ is equal to the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ avoiding consecutive numbers.  One would expect that $A_n = B_n^2$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the subsets issue. By negative numbers condition I meant that if lets say for n = 5, -3 is picked then 3 will not be present in the same subset.

Comment: Wait... are you saying that $\{-3,3\}$ is not one of the allowed subsets?  That doesn't violate the rule of consecutive positive numbers, and it has no consecutive negative numbers (*the interpretation I would have expected*), it has fewer than two negative numbers (*the interpretation it currently reads as*)... You will need to reword or clarify the conditions then.  Do you mean to say that the sequences have no consecutive positive numbers and any negative numbers appearing are not negatives of the positive numbers appearing?  Perhaps show us all valid subsets for $n=3$ (shouldn't be too bad

Comment: for n=3 (hope i am not missing something)  :                                                                 {-3},{-2},{-1},{1},{2},{3},{1,3},{1,-2},{1,-3},{2,-1},{2,-3},{3,-1},{3,-2},{1,-2,-3},{1,-2,-3},{1,3,-2},{2,-1,-3},{3,1,-1},{3,-1-2},{-1,-2,-3} etc..

Comment: so in general if a is in the subset so -a is out and if and only if a is positive then a-1, a+1 are out. note that if a = 1 then a-1 = -1 which can be presents.

Comment: You include $\{3,1,-1\}$, does this not contradict your comment saying "if $x$ is in the subset then $-x$ cannot be"?  Note also that $1-1=0\neq -1$, so your final sentence doesn't make sense.  Also you include $\{-1,-2,-3\}$ which both has consecutive negative numbers and has more than two negative numbers, so the original wording in the question post seems completely off.

Comment: sorry for the wrong description. yep you are right, {3,1,-1} clearly should not be counted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose for strong induction hypothesis that we know how to count $A_k$ for all $k<n$.  We wish to count $A_n$ using this information.

Each subset being counted for $A_n$ will fall into **exactly one** of the following categories

- $n$ is used (*implying $-n$ and $n-1$ are not used*) and $-n+1$ is used
- $n$ is used and $-n+1$ is not used
- $n$ is not used and $-n$ is used
- $n$ is not used and $-n$ is not used

In the first two cases, the subset ignoring $n$ and $-n+1$ will be a valid subset of $\{-n+2,\dots,-1,1,\dots,n-2\}$.  By induction hypothesis we know how to count the number of subsets in each case as $A_{n-2}$.

In the second two cases, the subset ignoring $n$ and $-n$ will be a valid subset of $\{-n+1,\dots,-1,1,n-1\}$.  By induction hypothesis we know how to count the number of subsets in each case as $A_{n-1}$.

Thus, $A_n = A_{n-1}+A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}+A_{n-2} = 2A_{n-1}+2A_{n-2}$

In order to have enough initial conditions to completely define the series, we will need then two initial values.  $A_0=1$ (*as $\emptyset$ is a valid subset of $\emptyset$ satisfying the conditions*) and $A_1 = 3$ (*as $\emptyset,\{-1\},\{1\}$ are all valid subsets of $\{-1,1\}$ satisfying the conditions*).

If you do not like zero as a starting point (*for some reason some people don't*), then $A_2 = 8$  as $\emptyset, \{-2\},\{-1\},\{1\},\{2\},\{-2,-1\},\{-2,1\},\{-1,2\}$ are all valid subsets of $\{-2,-1,1,2\}$.  (*as an aside, this follows our expected pattern, as $A_2=8=2\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 3=2A_0+2A_1$.  We expect, if we brute force a count for $A_3$ that it will be $2\cdot 8 + 2\cdot 3 = 22$*)

(*If you are looking for* **nonempty** *subsets satisfying the conditions, then the above work still applies.  Just subtract one to remove the emptyset from the count*)

---

Finding a closed form expression for $\begin{cases} A_n = 2A_{n-1}+2A_{n-2}\\ A_0=1\\ A_1=3\end{cases}$, we look to the characteristic polynomial, $x^2-2x-2=0$ which has roots $1-\sqrt{3}$ and $1+\sqrt{3}$

We expect then that $A_n = c_1(1-\sqrt{3})^n + c_2(1+\sqrt{3})^n$.

By using our initial conditions, we learn then that $1=c_1+c_2$ and $3=c_1(1-\sqrt{3})+c_2(1+\sqrt{3})$.  Continuing to solve, we find $c_1=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $c_2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ giving the final closed form:

$$A_n=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})(1-\sqrt{3})^n + (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})(1+\sqrt{3})^n$$